# Characteristic Equation of A Closed Loop System in Terms of PI Controller

Tags: controls

Just wondering if you could guide me on how to find the characteristic equation of a trasfer function G(s) (see below for G(s)) in terms of the coefficients in the PI controller?

G(s) = 45/(5s + 2)

No sure what to do here, as I'm used to just multiplying the error by the proportional gain - but there's no error value provided.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Given:
G(s) = 45/(5s + 2) (plant transfer function)
C(s) = Kp + Ki/s (PI Controller transfer function)
```

and assuming your system looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtt4tvujn6tpepv/block_diag.JPG

The equation of the closed loop transfer function is:

```
Gcl(s) =  C(s)G(s)/(1+C(s)G(s)) = CG/(1+CG)
```

In general, If you had another transfer function on the feedback path, H(s), 
the the closed loop transfer function becomes:

```
CG / (1 + CGH)
```

If you plug in G(s) and C(s) as shown above you will get the following closed loop transfer function after some algebraic simplification:

```
45*[Kp*s + Ki] / [5*s*s + (2 + 45*Kp)*s + 45*Ki]
```

and so the characteristic equation is

```
5*s*s + (2 + 45*Kp)*s + 45*Ki = 0
```

Notice how the integral term adds a pole to the system but has a side effect of also adding a zero which could produce unwanted transient behaviour if Kp is not chosen correctly. The presence of Kp in the s term in the denominator shows that the value of Kp will determine the damping ratio of the system and therefore determine the transient response.

More information on poles, zeros, and system dynamics:
http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf